# How to send two related parameters to a template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to execute an xslt template and I need two related parameters. The main idea of the xml is a list with clients and banks, something like this

```
<client>
    <id>lkjhg09876</q1:id>
    <name> name-value </name>
    <address> director-value </address>
    <bank-id> qwerty12345 <bank-id>
</client>

<bank>
    <id> qwerty12345 </id>
    <name> bank-name-value </name>
</bank>
```

So what I want is to call a template to process all the clients, I am doing it on this way

```
<xsl:call-template name="process-clients">
     <xsl:with-param name="client"
                     select="./client"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

But in order to display the bank name, I need the bank node related to my client, and I don't have that bank inside the template "process-clients".

How could I get the bank name inside the template or how can I send the bank name as a parameter to the template?

Comment: "*At this point I want to call a template to process all the clients*" What is "this point"?

Comment: At this moment/what I want, etc.

Comment: My question wasn't linguistic.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a key to get the `bank` node by `id`

```
<xsl:key name="banks" match="bank" use="id" />
```

Then, within your `process-clients` template, you can access the bank node by doing `key('banks', $client/bank-id)`. For example, to display the bank name it would look like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('banks', $client/bank-id)/name" />
```

If you did want to pass in the bank node as a parameter though, you could do it like this...

```
<xsl:call-template name="process-clients">
    <xsl:with-param name="client" select="client"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="bank" select="key('banks', client/bank-id)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing correctly, you start by processing the banks, then within each bank you want to process that bank's clients.

If so, you should do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="client-by-bank" match="client" use="bank-id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root-wrapper>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bank"/>
    </root-wrapper>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bank">
    <bank-wrapper>
        <!-- some bank details here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('client-by-bank', id)">
            <xsl:with-param name="bank-name" select="name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </bank-wrapper>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="client">
    <xsl:param name="bank-name" />
    <client-wrapper>
        <!-- client details here -->
        <!-- example of using bank name: -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$bank-name"/>
    </client-wrapper>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```